# SQL Server 'Login failed for user' not recorded in error log

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

The following exception is returned to our code during the following:

```
m_cnn = new SqlConnection();
m_cnn.ConnectionString = sxCnn;
m_cnn.Open();
```

---EXCEPTION INFORMATION---

> ```
> Exception: in OpenEx. 
> Msg=OpenEx failed. 
> Errors: Index #0
> Message: Login failed for user 'xyz'.
> LineNumber: 65536
> Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
> Procedure: 
> Number: 18456
> State: 1
> ```

The problem I am having is that I cannot find this entry in the SQL error logs in order to look-up the state. For instance, we saw this exception at 11:43am today and when I go to the logs, there is no entry for that time.

Is there something that we need to do in order to enable this logging? We have the 'Failed logins only' option selected in the database properties under Security | Login auditing. Yet, we see nothing in there for this issue.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Windows authentication or mixed?  If windows, try checking the windows security log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was occurring because of two main issues:

1. A few switches on our network were bad
2. We are making an obscene amount of concurrent connections to the database

We have fixed 1 and the number of issues has drastically reduced. We are in the process of rewriting the connections made from apps (I actually asked another question while trying to implement a fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150616/caching-across-applications-in-net-on-a-windows-machine))

Answer (score 0):

You could be having problems with your connection string. It shouldn't be a variable in code, it should be set in your web.config and pulled from there. Here's mine in web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MYSQL1;Initial Catalog=MyDATABASE;User ID=dummyUser;Password=dummyPW" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and here's I pull it from code:

```
mcnn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Also, If there is a spelling error, or if your missing something, in your connection string, you won't be able to even reach the database to attempt a log in. sql would have nothing to log. Could be worth double checking ^_^

Comment: Connection string is not an issue because it works 99% of the time and the conn string doesn't change. This login failed issue occurs randomly on our network.

Comment: 99% of the time, and occurs randomly? It should either work, or not work. My guess is that your program isn't reaching your database.

Comment: It should. That's the frustrating part about this. The db is a an awesome dedicated box and it's enterprise level. My main issue is figuring out why this is not getting logged to the error log.

Comment: I just tried the connection string again based on your edit and it worked perfectly. I can get data back from the db. The conn string is in code (don't ask why!) and it doesn't change.

Comment: string m_sxSqlConnect   = @"Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xyz;Initial Catalog=SomeCatalog;Data Source=SomeCatalog;Password=SomePassword";

Comment: The conn string above is what we use (edited a little to remove sensitive info).

Comment: @AboutDev The problem with that is if you have to use the string multiple times throughout your application, it gets harder to keep track of. Especially if changes take place, you would have to find and edit each string amongst all your code, increasing the possibility that a mistake has been made. If you have one string in web.config, and pull all your strings from there, any changes that need to be done, can be done in one nice, easy to find, spot

Answer (score 0):

The logging of login failures is controlled by the [`AuditLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.auditlevel.aspx) setting.

Comment: We already have the login auditing set to Failure through the Management Studio as I specified in my original post. It still isn't working.

Comment: That it would mean you're not connecting to the server you think you're connecting to.

Comment: Again, the connection string is static in code. It it works 99.9% of the time, then it's not a problem with which server it's going to.