# Caching across Applications in .Net on a Windows Machine

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I am trying to implement caching in .Net such that the cached data is accessible not just by an application that may run multiple times on the same machine but by other types of applications that may run on the machine. They could be windows services, web services, win forms etc.

I have looked at System.Runtime.Caching (because Enterprise Application Blocks Caching is going to become obsolete) as a means to achieve this. The default MemoryCache is insufficient to achieve this as I don't believe that it work across app domains.

Is there a way I can implement the kind of caching I am looking for or is there a caching dll of some sort (must be free) that I can use to achieve my goal?

Is there a way to use System.Runtime.Caching with IsolatedStorage scoped to MachineLevel?

I've looked at memcache too and can't use it because we need this to run on windows machines. I started looking at SharedCache (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-cache/AdvanceCaching.aspx) and am curious about the pitfalls it has as well.

Thanks.

---

**-- Revision 1 --**

---

I think the optimal solution for me would use the **Caching** object to a **Memory Mapped File** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx). So the question I have now is whether anyone has done that with the System.Runtime.Caching object. There must be a way to extend it if necessary...examples of how to do so would also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [AppFabric Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731.aspx). It's a Windows Server technology from Microsoft. It's free.

I should also say that if you like memcached, you *can* use that on Windows as well, and in fact Microsoft Azure team members used to recommend it, before the AppFabric caching was available on Windows Azure.

Comment: I'm trying to implement caching on client machines...it may not be feasible to run AppFabric on all their machines. I'm just looking for a caching scheme that is machine wide..that's all..just a simple dll to do the job :-)

Comment: +1 to use AppFabric of MemCached if needed. Also depending on your actual needs (beyond creating fancy local cache accesible from processes under different accounts and other fun stuff...) you may consider go the route that browsers use - simple file based local cache.

Comment: Alexei - AppFabric is a great tool. However, its not something I can use on a client machine running xp. File based local cache is a workable idea. Do you know if the System.Runtime.Cache supports file based local cache?

Answer (score 0):

Have you evaluated Microsoft Velocity? Take a look - I believe if you are not okay with using the AppFabric Cache, this should work out for you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861287.aspx#id0450004

For simple client based caching, you can look at file based caching.

Comment: Sajoshi - Yes I have looked at Velocity. It's a great tool that will make our lives easier...just not today. It's not production ready yet but when it is, I will definitely be spending time with it.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/03/22/caching-application-data-by-using-multiple-cache-objects-in-an-asp-net-application.aspx